# A better way to write the same deep callback in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm writing a piece of code with that makes an HTML element blink three times using a function (from RaphaelJS) with a signature like `animate(params, delay, easing, callback)`. The idea is that `callback` executes after `delay` milliseconds, when the animation is finished. So with that I have the following code:

```
var theElement = anElement;

function animateOpacity(newOpacity, callback) {
    theElement.animate({ opacity: newOpacity }, 500, null, callback);
}

function blink() {
    animateOpacity(0.1, function() {
        animateOpacity(1, function() {
            animateOpacity(0.1, function() {
                animateOpacity(1, function() {
                    animateOpacity(0.1, function() {
                        theElement.remove();
                    });
                });
             });
         });
     });
  }
```

...which looks horrible. Does anybody know of a better way to call this same `animateOpacity` function as callbacks without all these nested anonymous functions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code like this (this is what I call callback loop):

```
function blink() {
    var opacities = [0.1, 1, 0.1, 1, 0.1];
    animate(opacities, 0);
}

function animate(arr, i) {
    if (i == arr.length) {
        theElement.remove();
        return;
    }
    animateOpacity(arr[i], function () {
        animate(arr, i++);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use common code and a counter:

```
function blink(theElement, numBlinks) {

    var lastOpacity = 0.1;

    function animateOpacity(newOpacity, callback) {
        theElement.animate({ opacity: newOpacity }, 500, null, callback);
    }

    function next() {
        --numBlinks;
        if (numBlinks > 0) {
            lastOpacity = lastOpacity < 1 ? 1: 0.1;
            animateOpacity(lastOpacity, next);
        } else {
            theElement.remove();
        }
    }

    animateOpacity(0.1, next);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd explode it in several callbacks called conditionnally:

```
var theElement = anElement,
    blinksRemaining = 3;

function animateOpacity(newOpacity, callback) {
    theElement.animate({ opacity: newOpacity }, 500, null, callback);
}
function removeElement() {
    theElement.remove();
}

function fadeOutThenIn() {
    blinksRemaining--;
    animateOpacity(0.1, blink);
}

function blink() {
    animateOpacity(1, blinksRemaining ? fadeOutThenIn : removeElement);
}

blink();
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think the following should work:

```
var theElement = anElement;

function animateOpacity(newOpacity, callback) {
    theElement.animate({ opacity: newOpacity }, 500, null, callback);
}

function blink() {
    var args = [0.1, 1, 0.1, 1, 0.1];
    var func = function() {
        theElement.remove();
    };
    for (var i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        func = animateOpacity.bind(null, args[i], func);
    }
    func();
}
```

The idea here is to create the functions from inner to outer, binding the inner function as an argument to the new outer function along with the other argument at each step.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [jQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) ([tutorial)](http://calje.eu/index.php/jquery-deferreds/). But there are [other](https://github.com/sudhirj/simply-deferred) libraries that give that functionality too.

Of course you could also do something like this (not tested):

```
function blink(opacity, count) {
    opacity = opacity === .1 ? 1 : .1;
    if(count < 3) {
        animateOpacity(opacity, blink.bind(null, opacity, ++count));
    }
}
blink(1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setInterval() or setTimeout() functions

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

much cleaner way

use a conditional for checking the three times

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a conttolling function with an interval

```
function blinkingBlinker(newOpacity, callback){
    var blink_count = 0;
    var blink = setInterval(animateOpacity,1000);

    function animateOpacity(){
        blink_count++;

       function animateOpacity() {
          theElement.animate({ opacity: newOpacity }, 500, null, callback);
          }

        if (blink_count==3){
            clearInterval(blink)
        }
    }}
```

So, you call the blinkingBlinker function and it internally runs animateOpacity every second until the blink count exceeds the number of blinks you want.

Answer (score 0):

The blink effect can be imitated using the following css

```
    @-webkit-keyframes blinker { from {opacity:1.0;} to {opacity:0.1;} }
    @keyframes blinker { from {opacity:1.0;} to {opacity:0.1;} }
    #element{

        text-decoration:blink;
        -webkit-animation-name:blinker;
        animation-name:blinker;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count:10;
        animation-iteration-count:10;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(1.0,0,0,1.0);
        animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(1.0,0,0,1.0);
        -webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
        animation-duration:0.5s; 
     }
```